# Connect to a secure database using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

How do you specify the username and password for a JDBC connection when acessing a secure database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to specify them in [`DriverManager.getConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), like

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + dbname,
                                              dbusername, dbpassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

The DriverManager.getConnection method has a signature which takes a username and password. In addition, JDBC drivers tend to support specifying them on the URL